# Selecting a JSON object by number not by name

Tags: javascript, json

I try to store a JSON object with informations in multiple languages. Im not even sure they way i did it is good, any suggestions are welcome.

My current problem ist, that i dont know how to access the first language without knowing what language it is.

```
var Data = {

  "NameIntern": "Something intern",
  "en":  {
          "Name": "Some name",
          "ModuleOrder": "123,333,22"  }
};
```

`document.write(Data[1].Name);`

I just want to access the second object, sometimes its "en", sometimes its "de".

Thanks for any tipps!

Comment: are there always will be only two properties in the `Data` object?

Comment: Could be more then two properties

Comment: Could be more than 2 languages? or what, if more, add others, anyway you definitely have fixed language translations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure javascript solution:
First: You get the keys of the object:

```
var keys = Object.keys(Data);
```

Then: The keys are stored in a array. You can access them with an index. Like:

```
Data[keys[0]]
```

Now: You can use a foor loop or whatever you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Data is an object its not array so you cant access it like Data[0] you can access it like Data.en.

but as you say you dont know any thing about en or de so i suggest that you form the Data object like this :

```
var Data =[{
lang:"en",
langData:{
   Name:"Some name"
}
```

}]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Data = {

  "NameIntern": "Something intern",
  "en":  {
          "Name": "Some name",
          "ModuleOrder": "123,333,22"  }
};

var index = 0;
$.each(Data, function(key, val){
  index += 1;
  if (index == 2){
    // key is the language, like in this example key is 'en'
    console.log(key);
  }  
});
```

Comment: This worked for my testdata in plain javascript. But i didnt mention that i use node.js, mongodb and ejs without having Jquery installed on node.js. Sorry for the lack of information, i thought i makes it more confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var name = (Data.en || Data.de || {})['Name'];
```

1. `(Data.en || Data.de || {})` get's value of *Data.en* or *Data.de* if both doesn't exist, return empty object, so that script doesn't throw exception for *Name* property
2. `()['Name']` same as `myObject['Name']`, `myObject.Name`
3. assign value to `name` variable, it will be *Some name* or `undefined` at least

If you have more languages, add them all, notice: it will return first found lang

```
var name = (Data.en || Data.de || Data.ru || Data.fr || {})['Name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys` method to get list of object property names:

```
console.log(Data[Object.keys(Data)[1]]['Name']);   // "Some name"
```